# Fastest Way to Find All Positions of Every distinct Character in a String

Tags: python, string

> *Suppose we have a string, say, **"122113"** and we are supposed to **find all the occurrences of every character in the String.***

A naive approach will be like this:

```
string = str( raw_input() )  # for example: "122113"
distinct_char = list( set(string) )
occurrences=[]
for element in distinct_char:
    temp=[]
    for j in range(len(string)):
        if(string[j]==element):
            temp.append(j)
    occurrences.append(temp)
print(occurrences)  # output for "122113" would be [[0, 3, 4], [1, 2], [5]]
                    #because 1 occurrs at : 0, 3, 4
                    #        2 occurrs at : 1, 2
                    #        3 occurrs at : 5
```

> But, this is quite slow *if the length of the String is Large*.
>   **So, is there any faster solution?**

(Consider the string is only made up of lower english alphabets and the length of the string may be $10^12$

Comment: Hint: iterate once through the list, and update a dictionary mapping characters to positions as you go

Comment: I second that, it scales linearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a defaultdict (with an empty list as default value) and update the indices list while iterating through the string:

```
from collections import defaultdict
string = str(raw_input())
occurences = defaultdict(list)
for i, c in enumerate(string):
  occurences[c].append(i)
print occurences
```

Then use a list comprehension to get your list of occurrences:

```
occurences = [l for l in occurences.values()]
```

Comment: will it work fast enough if, length(s) becomes significantly large?

Comment: @TuhinKarmakar Well, it took 5 seconds for a 10000000 long string on my super slow computer, you can test for yourself if you want to see whether it's fast or not.

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry, my earlier answer misunderstood the question.)

You could use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this:

```py
import collections

very_long_string = "abcdefghij" * 1000000

indices = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i, c in enumerate(very_long_string):
    indices[c].append(i)
```

`indices` will then be a dict that maps each character into their indices (example obviously not for the `very_long_string` above, but a shorter one).

```py
{
    "a": [0, 10],
    "b": [1, 11],
    "c": [2, 12],
    "d": [3, 13],
    "e": [4, 14],
    "f": [5, 15],
    "g": [6, 16],
    "h": [7, 17],
    "i": [8, 18],
    "j": [9, 19],
}
```

It takes about 3 seconds to do this for 10 000 000 characters on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to convert the string characters into numbers and use the number to increment values in an array. The code could be as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def alph_to_num(alph):
    return ord(alph.lower())-97

string='alsblnasdglasdaoerngeaglbneronbiwernblnerl'
array=np.zeros(26)

for alph in string:
    index=alph_to_num(alph)
    array[index]=array[index]+1
print(array)
```

which gives: `[5. 4. 0. 2. 5. 0. 3. 0. 1. 0. 0. 6. 0. 6. 2. 0. 0. 4. 3. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.
 0. 0.]`

Here I have made the array of length 26 since you know that it is just lowercase english letters. This also means that it is easier to interpret the resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

No import solution - given that you know it's only lower case alphabet you can precreate a list of lists of size 26, then iterating through just append the index of each character found to the appropriate position.

```
input_lst="abcdefgaabbfegddsa"
occurence_lst = [[] for i in range(26)]
for index in range(len(input_lst)):
    occurence_lst[ord(input_lst[index]) - 97].append(index)

print(occurence_lst)

[0, 7, 8, 17], [1, 9, 10], [2], [3, 14, 15], [4, 12], [5, 11], [6, 13], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [16], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Python 2.7, option 1 (I did the dictionary so that one can tell which letter corresponded to the indices):

```
s = raw_input()
occurances = {}
pos = 0

for let in s:
  if let in occurances:
    occurances[let].append(pos)
  else:
    occurances[let] = [pos]
  pos += 1

print(occurances)
```

average time for 10000 runs on '122113': 2.55961418152e-06

average time for 10000 runs on 'a;lkdsfowquebtgafdnga;llkl;uihnbr,afdh;glakhhehjehrjehjeoguhaberna': 2.39794969559e-05

average time for 500 runs on 'alkdsfowquebtgafdngallkl'*1000: 0.00993875598907

option 2:

```
s = raw_input()
occurances = {}

for i,let in enumerate(s):
  if let in occurances:
    occurances[let].append(i)
  else:
    occurances[let] = [i]

print(occurances)
```

average time for 10000 runs on '122113': 7.02269077301e-06

average time for 10000 runs on 'a;lkdsfowquebtgafdnga;llkl;uihnbr,afdh;glakhhehjehrjehjeoguhaberna': 2.39794969559e-05

average time for 500 runs on 'alkdsfowquebtgafdngallkl'*1000: 0.00974810600281

(Test times from repl.it running python 2.7)

Edit: Depending on exactly how it's used in the script, `defaultdict` can be faster or slower than just using `dict`